# Setting Up PHP Push/Pull With Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, version-control, commit

*Bear with me here ... I can't show exact examples or provide a link to the web server for security reasons. If anything more is needed I will gladly provide it.*

## *What I HAVE:*

[image: Current Setup]

I have a server that hosts an internal networked **intranet** for my company.

- Coded with **PHP**, MySQL, HTML, etc
- **Ubuntu 14.04LTS**
- Normal Apache Web Server Configuration

  - Login access
  - Couple hundred PHP files for different pages/features needed for the company
- Maintenance

  - FTP into the directories (shown below)
  - Manually edit PHP files with **Notepad++**
  - Test in **Beta Directory** -> move to -> **Secure** (overwriting current file there)
  - I know this procedure for maintaining is horrible so I'm trying to come up with a better solution
  - [image: www Directory]
  - [image: Example Files]

## *What I NEED:*

[image: Desired Setup]

- Features

  - IDE Connectivity (Aptana,Eclipse,etc)
  - Commit/Push/Pull Capable with Server from IDE
  - Version Control
  - Keep backups for Rollbacks
  - Test & Main Server
  - Like how I have a Beta and Secure Directory for testing and releasing to everyone

**What needs to be done on the Ubuntu Server in order to accept push/pull requests, store multiple versions, and store commit messages?**

**Do I need to install anything on the Ubuntu server in order to communicate with the remote computer I'm trying to access from?**

Comment: Set up GIT on the server, use the repository as master, and set up a small cron-job running "git pull" in the folder where the site is active, or just run it via SSH from the IT computer.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Would the repo be located somewhere on the server? Will it all be setup automagically when installing GIT? The problem is whenever I've tried researching this I get sent to Github but I want a __local repository__.

Comment: It won't be setup automatically, no, but yes, the repository would be located on the server. If you want to avoid setting up locally, you could run it via Github.com, just set up a payment plan so you can make the repository private

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I can't put it through Github because it's confidential company data (even if it is private). How would hosting on Github help though? The code has to be on the server (unless it pulls from Github somehow...).

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Also, from your first comment, can an IDE (used on IT PC) control the push and pull or does the server have to do something as well? If something has to happen on the server's side, can it be activated when it receives a request from the IDE (used on IT PC)?

Comment: Maybe, will be the answer to that. You could create a reachable webpage with a button you could click to fetch the latest updates. Or, again, either just run a cron job or open an ssh shell to the server.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Then how does it work fine with Github? You only have to push or pull from the IDE. Github must do something on its side.

Comment: If you can connect the IDE to Github, you should be able to connect it to your local installation of Git. I don't know the IDEs, so I have no idea, but in theory it's just about defining the settings needed - paths, etc.